# How do I make this caroussel slider mouse / touch draggable (Tailwind CSS and Alpine JS)

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I am trying to build a website and have this carousel, that was made with Alpine JS and Tailwind CSS. I took the Alpine Javascript from a template and it works according to specifications. But I would want to make it mouse draggable as well.

Here is the carousel slider

```
<div class="mt-24">

    <script>
      window.carousel = function () {
        return {
          container: null,
          prev: null,
          next: null,
          init() {
            this.container = this.$refs.container
  
            this.update();
  
            this.container.addEventListener('scroll', this.update.bind(this), {passive: true});
          },
          update() {
            const rect = this.container.getBoundingClientRect();
  
            const visibleElements = Array.from(this.container.children).filter((child) => {
              const childRect = child.getBoundingClientRect()
  
              return childRect.left >= rect.left && childRect.right <= rect.right;
            });
  
            if (visibleElements.length > 0) {
              this.prev = this.getPrevElement(visibleElements);
              this.next = this.getNextElement(visibleElements);
            }
          },
          getPrevElement(list) {
            const sibling = list[0].previousElementSibling;
  
            if (sibling instanceof HTMLElement) {
              return sibling;
            }
  
            return null;
          },
          getNextElement(list) {
            const sibling = list[list.length - 1].nextElementSibling;
  
            if (sibling instanceof HTMLElement) {
              return sibling;
            }
  
            return null;
          },
          scrollTo(element) {
            const current = this.container;
  
            if (!current || !element) return;
  
            const nextScrollPosition =
              element.offsetLeft +
              element.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2 -
              current.getBoundingClientRect().width / 2;
  
            current.scroll({
              left: nextScrollPosition,
              behavior: 'smooth',
            });
          }
        };
      }
      
    </script>
    <style>
      .scroll-snap-x {
        scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
      }
  
      .snap-center {
        scroll-snap-align: center;
      }
  
      .no-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
        display: none;
      }
  
      .no-scrollbar {
        -ms-overflow-style: none;
        scrollbar-width: none;
      }
    </style>
    <div class="flex mx-auto items-center">
      <div x-data="carousel()" x-init="init()" class="relative overflow-hidden group">
        <div x-ref="container"
             class="ml-4 flex overflow-x-scroll scroll-snap-x space-x-4 no-scrollbar touch-pan-x cursor-pointer">
          
          {% for origin in origins %}
          <div class="group/item relative ml-4 flex-auto flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 w-4/5 sm:w-4/5 xl:w-2/5 rounded-lg bg-gray-100 items-center justify-center snap-center overflow-hidden shadow-md"><!-- items container -->
            <div class="min-w-full h-full rounded-lg bg-gray-100 overflow-hidden shadow-md">
               <div><img src="{{ origin.imgurl }}" alt="{{ origin.alt }}" class="object-cover h-96" /></div>
               <div class="absolute bg-gray-800 bg-opacity-0 group-hover/item:bg-opacity-50 top-2/3 inset-x-0 text-center px-2 py-3">
                  <div class="text-2xl text-transparent group-hover/item:text-emerald-500 font-extrabold uppercase">{{ origin.name }}</div>
                  <div class="text-xl text-transparent group-hover/item:text-white font-bold">{{ origin.country }}</div> 
               </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div @click="scrollTo(prev)" x-show="prev !== null"
             class="block absolute top-1/2 left-0 bg-white text-3xl p-2 rounded-full transition-transform ease-in-out transform -translate-x-full -translate-y-1/2 group-hover:translate-x-0 cursor-pointer">
          <div><ion-icon name="chevron-back-outline"></ion-icon></div>
        </div>
        <div @click="scrollTo(next)" x-show="next !== null"
             class="block absolute top-1/2 right-0 bg-white p-2 text-3xl rounded-full transition-transform ease-in-out transform translate-x-full -translate-y-1/2 group-hover:translate-x-0 cursor-pointer">
          <div><ion-icon name="chevron-forward-outline"></ion-icon></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried adding Alpine script from a different carousel that has this function, but it does not do anything. My understanding of Javascript is rudimentary.